# Date Range Limit SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a report that calculates how many contracts have been funded each month for the year 2014. The problem is I am trying to limit the dates, meaning I want the user to be able to see of how many funded contracts there are of each month but not passed the present month. So we are in June right now, I do not want the user to be able to access the month of June or July because the month hasn't been over yet, where as the passed months can be seen but only up until the first day of 2014. So, I do NOT want the current month. But only up to the last day of the previous month of every month. I believe my Where Clause is where the flaw is because I'm still new at the function of GetDate and Datediff.

```
 ALTER PROC spGetAdminTotalYTD
    (
      @Begin_Date DATETIME ,
      @End_Date DATETIME ,
      @program INT = NULL
    )
 AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @year INT
        SET @year = 2014

        SELECT  d.name ,
                a.dealer_code ,
                b.last_name ,
                b.city ,
                b.state ,
                b.phone ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Feburary ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November ,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December ,
                COUNT(1) AS YTD
        FROM    tdealer a
                JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id
                JOIN tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id
                JOIN tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
        WHERE   YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year
                AND c.Funded_date >= DATEADD(MONTH,
                                             DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 4,
                                             0)
                AND c.Funded_date < DATEADD(MONTH,
                                            DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1,
                                            0)
                AND c.program_id = @program
                AND c.funded_date BETWEEN @Begin_Date AND @End_Date
        GROUP BY d.name ,
                a.dealer_code ,
                b.last_name ,
                b.city ,
                b.state ,
                b.phone
    END
```